# Chrome - ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash

I'm having a bit of a problem in Chrome, I'm getting this error within my console window "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE", if you expand the banner it will not load the video. I've already set my security to allow all domains "Security.allowDomain("*")", I'm not sure if it has to do with the url of the video not being secure with "http" rather then "https" any ideas would be great?.

URL: http://espn.go.com/?adtar=kgsm

Comment: That error usually comes when you try to load in external http content in an https page.  You can proxy the content via something that is in https, or just access your containing page via http.  At any rate, it doesn't have anything to do with AS3 or Flash.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try using a secured url to remedy this problem I'm having.